# Manage space between words (.bat)

Tags: bash, unix, batch-file, shell-script

The question might not be so good to ask, but I am really not getting a workaround for same. I have a `.bat` file which connects UNIX (using PuTTY command line plink) server and further executes a `.sh` script. From `.bat` files I am passing parameters to my Unix shell script, which is working well. But it is causing an issue for one parameter value.

**Value:**

```
'[List Of Values Parent (UDA).Value]="LOV RAF_PO_PRM_TYPE_ADM"'
```

I want to pass above value in same format. I tried below mentioned way:

1)  `"[List Of Values Parent (UDA).Value]=\"LOV RAF_PO_PRM_TYPE_ADM\""`

I thought passing it in `""` will solve the issue but not working for me. Now the issue is when I run my `.bat` file, it breaks my string which looks like this when i print the value:

```
"[List Of Values Parent (UDA).Value]=\"LOV
```

because of SPACE it is not reading full string, and I can not replace SPACE with anything else, I need to have that space. In my Unix script I read the parameter in following way (coming from .bat):

```
admfilter="'$admFilter'"
```

This is one of parameter field in server manager command. But issue is at `.bat`, not at script. When I replace that white SPACE with `_` everything is working fine. But I need to have that space.

**Script:**

```
@ECHO OFF

setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set n=0
for %%a in (%*) do (
   set vector[!n!]=%%a
   set /A n+=1
)


SET admPath=%vector[0]%
SET admdatatype=%vector[1]%
SET admeaimethod=%vector[2]%
SET admprefix=%vector[3]%
SET gatewayname=%vector[4]%
SET enterpriseName=%vector[5]%
SET serverName=%vector[6]%
SET serveruserId=%vector[7]%
SET serverpassword=%vector[8]%
SET admFilter=%vector[9]%
SET userId=%vector[10]%
SET password=%vector[11]%
SET host=%vector[12]%
SET sudoUser=%vector[13]%
SET localPath=%vector[14]%

echo %admPath%
echo %admdatatype%
echo %admeaimethod%
echo %admprefix%
echo %gatewayname%
echo %enterpriseName%
echo %serverName%
echo %serveruserId%
echo %serverpassword%
echo %admFilter%

echo y | "C:\Program Files\PuTTY\plink" -ssh %userId%@%host% -pw %password% exit

"C:\Program Files\PuTTY\plink" -ssh -t %userId%@%host% -pw %password% "PATH=/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin /opt/siebel/w44gq8sw/ExportLov.sh %admPath% %admdatatype% %admeaimethod% %admprefix% %gatewayname% %enterpriseName% %serverName% %serveruserId% %serverpassword% %admFilter% %password% %sudoUser% %localPath% " > LOV_export_success.txt 2>&1
```

Calling of `.bat`:

```
LovExport.bat "/global/u70/globepfdev/ADM" "LOV" "Upsert" "export_ADM" "GatewayName" "EnterpriseName" "ServerName" "ServerUser"  "ServerPassword" "[List Of Values Parent (UDA).Value]=\"LOV RAF_PO_PRM_TYPE_ADM\"" "userId" "Password" "Host" "'SudoUser'" "/opt/siebel/w44gq8sw/exportFile"
```

I have edited my actual values, and only showing relevant details. When I check `echo %admFilter%` I see the above mentioned output.

Comment: i would try it with the String from your 1) with one little change. I’d put a \ before the Space after LOV like this:: LOV\ RAF_PO... so the space is prevented as a String Character and not used as a Argument Spacer

Comment: Try `"[List Of Values Parent (UDA).Value]=""LOV RAF_PO_PRM_TYPE_ADM"""` with _doubled_ inner quotes. It should pass the value correct to an executable even thought `echo %admFilter%` keeps inner quotes doubled.

Comment: @JosefZ sure sir I will try this and let you know.

Comment: @konqui I already tried that but didn't worked.

Comment: It has nothing to do with spaces.  The quotes are the problem.  Quotes are used to protect special characters and spaces but you can't protect quotes with quotes.

Comment: Strangely enough someone by the name of Sharma had the same problem as you on another StackExchange site. [Calling a batch file with arguments having quotes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4327707/calling-a-batch-file-with-arguments-having-quotes)

Comment: @Squashman Thanks for finding out one for me, but that's not me for sure :).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The essential problem is that you have quotes that you need in your argument and you also have spaces that you need in your argument. So the work around for this is to surround the whole thing in quotes and double up the quotes that need to be part of the argument so that the cmd parser sees it as one big argument. Then you can use string replacement to make the double quotes into a single set of quotes.

Here is a simplified solution to your problem for that particular argument. You will execute the bat file like this.

```
readargs.bat "[List Of Values Parent (UDA).Value]=""LOV RAF_PO_PRM_TYPE_ADM""
```

Then readargs.bat will do this.

```
@echo off
echo %1
set "arg=%~1"
set "arg=%arg:""="%"
echo %arg%
pause
```

And the output will be.

```
"[List Of Values Parent (UDA).Value]=""LOV RAF_PO_PRM_TYPE_ADM""
[List Of Values Parent (UDA).Value]="LOV RAF_PO_PRM_TYPE_ADM"
```

Comment: I will test tomorrow and accept it.